# Get array of one url param

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

I want  get the url-param ids, but It will not work. Is here everyone who can help me?
The following code doesn't work.

Url:

```
http://localhost:9000/rest/alerts?ids[]=123?ids[]=456
```

Routes.conf

```
GET /restws/alerts{ids} controllers.AlertService.findAlertsForIds(ids: List[String])
```

AlertService.java

```
public static Result findAlertsForIds(List<String> ids){

 return ok("Coole Sache"); 

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing ids as string like this
`http://<hostname>:9000/rest/alerts?ids=123,456,789`

and then get the array by applying the split() function on the string.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 32):

This kind of parameter binding works out-of-the box with query-string parameters.

Your route have to be declared like this :

```
GET /restws/alerts controllers.AlertService.findAlertsForIds(ids: List[String])
```

And your URL should follow this pattern :

```
http://localhost:9000/rest/alerts?ids=123&ids=456
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, you've got a lot of options... all a little different from each other. The following URL formats can be used:

- `/foo/bar?color=red&color=blue`
- `/foo/bar?color=red,blue`
- `/foo/bar?color=[red,blue]`
- `/foo/bar?color[]=red,blue`

You can either:

### 1. Use Play Forms

Simple config:

```
// form definition
case class ColorParams(colors:Seq[String])

val myForm = Form(formMapping(
  "color" -> seq(text(1, 32)))(ColorParams.apply)(ColorParams.unapply)

// in your controller method call
val params = myForm.bindFromRequest()
```

Example URL: `/foo/bar?color[]=red,blue` will become `List("red","blue")`

Sadly this isn't as robust, as many API's use the format `color=red,blue` or `color=red&color=blue`

### 2. Create your own custom query string parser

More elaborate, but you can write constraints, tests, and leave everything to the Router. Pro is that invalid queries never make it to your Controller.

Then you just use it in your Routes file like:

```
case class ColorParams(colors:List[MyColorEnum])
```

`GET /foo/bar? controllers.Example.getBar(color:ColorParams)`

Example URL: `/foo/bar?color=red,blue`

Because you're parsing the string yourself, you can many any string layout in this post work as desired with this method. See full details on [QueryStringBindable](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.4/api/java/play/mvc/QueryStringBindable.html). I'll add a full example later.

### 3. Define your array parameter in the Routes file

`GET /foo/bar? controllers.Example.getBar(color:Seq[String])`

```
// inside Example.scala
def getBar( colors:Seq[String] ) = {
    ???
}
```

Example URL: `/foo/bar?color=red&color=blue`

Note: I used `color` in the Routes file, which is the name in the URL, but `colors` in the `getBar` method, for clarity. These names don't have to match, just the types.

#### Gotchas

Note this can be tricky, because `/foo/bar?color=red,blue` becomes Seq('red,blue'), that is a Seq of one string, **not** two strings, but it will still display in the debugger as `Seq(red,blue)`. The proper value to see in the debugger would be `Seq(red, blue)`, notice that space? Tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Play 2.5:

```scala
// http://localhost:9000/myview?option=qwer=5&option=pass&option=43,56&otherOption=5

class MyController extends Controller  {
  def myview() = Action { implicit request =>
    println(request.queryString)
```

returns:

```scala
Map(option -> Buffer(qwer=5, pass, 43,56), otherOption -> Buffer(5))
```