# Is it possible pass in same request parameter multiple times in Play and Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, api-design

Can I pass in the same request parameter multiple times in Play? From the documentation it seems that `request.queryString` returns a map but I'm not sure how it handles duplicate param keys.

For example, to search for photos that have both John and Sarah:

`/photo?member=John&member=Sarah`

Comment: Is it this your are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164337/get-array-of-one-url-param.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't, only first occurrence will be taken into account.

Anyway you can for an instance use comma separated list of params like:

```
/photo?members=John,Sarah
```

and then `split()` it to the String array by comma character.

Comment: This is not HTTP standard and you need extra logic with defining the split character. Might also cause problems, if a name contains an ",". The URL given by poliu2s is standard and software should handle it correctly. Play supports duplicate values.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, at least with Play 2.5:

```
// http://localhost:9000/myview?option=qwer=5&option=pass&option=43,56&otherOption=5

class MyController extends Controller  {
  def myview() = Action { implicit request =>
    println(request.queryString)
```

returns:

```
Map(option -> Buffer(qwer=5, pass, 43,56), otherOption -> Buffer(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in the same parameter with the same key, I could just accept a comma separated list. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164337/get-array-of-one-url-param).